# disable options in one menu based upon selection in another

Tags: jquery, html-select

I've got one menu that, when a value is selected from it, enables to other menus where a month can be selected (a begin month and an end month).  I want to add to it the restriction that the end month cannot be before the begin month, and I'm not sure how to go about doing it.

here's the jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/5ZqKE/

Something like this maybe?

```
$("#recurBegin").change(function(){
  var begin = $("#recurBegin option:selected").attr("value");
  //disable options in #recurEnd where the value is less than that of #recurBegin.
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/njNwN/)</kbd>

```
var end = $('#recurEnd');
$('#recurBegin').change(function () {
    var index = $(this).find('option:selected').index();
    end.find('option').show();
    end.find('option:lt(' + index + ')').hide();
});
```

---

[.index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/)

[:lt()](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/)

[.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

Comment: one more thing...I modified the code in the last line to (index + 1) so that it only allows the user to select the month AFTER the month they selected in the first menu.  But when you select December in the first menu, it makes the second one not work right.

Answer (score 1):

I think this would give you what you want.

html:

```
<div class="col-sm-9">
    <select name="catFrequency" id="catFrequency" onchange="toggleAnnual();">
        <option value="0">Monthly</option>
        <option value="1">Annual</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-8">
    <select  name="monthSelect" id="recurBegin" value="Select Month">
        <option value='' selected></option>
        <option value='01'>January</option>
        <option value='02'>February</option>
        <option value='03'>March</option>
        <option value='04'>April</option>
        <option value='05'>May</option>
        <option value='06'>June</option>
        <option value='07'>July</option>
        <option value='08'>August</option>
        <option value='09'>September</option>
        <option value='10'>October</option>
        <option value='11'>November</option>
        <option value='12'>December</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-3 clearfix">
    <label class="control-label">Ending Month:</label>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-9">
    <select name="monthSelect" id="recurEnd" value="Select Month">
    </select>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
$("#recurBegin").change(function(){
    $("#recurEnd").empty();
    var add = false;

    $("#recurBegin option").each(function(i, val){
        if($(this).is(':selected')) add = true;
        if(add){
            $("#recurEnd").append($(this).clone());
        }        
    });
});
```

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PpESb/

Answer (score 0):

You could just use option index:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5ZqKE/2/)

```
$("#recurBegin").change(function () {
    var begin = $(this).find('option:selected').index();
    $('#recurEnd').find('option').prop('disabled', false).filter(':lt(' + begin + ')').prop('disabled', true);
    $('#recurEnd').val(function(){return $(this).find('option:enabled:first').val()});
});
```